# Missing zero in left MD5 hash

Tags: node.js, md5

I am testing a code to generate a 26-character custom MD5 Hash from a file and it works correctly except for those files that generate a hash with a zero in the first left position, in which case the zero disappears and the hash remains in 25 characters instead of 26, the code is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');

var DEFAULTS = {
    charSet: [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    maxLength: 26,
    right: false
};

var config = {
    charSet: DEFAULTS.charSet,
    maxLength: DEFAULTS.maxLength,
    right: DEFAULTS.right
};

function add (x, y, base) {
    var value, digit, carry;
    var output = [];
    var length = Math.max(x.length, y.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        value = (x[i] || 0) + (y[i] || 0) + (carry || 0);
        digit = value % base;
        carry = (value - digit) / base;
        output.push(digit);
    }

    return (carry > 0) ? output.concat(carry) : output;
}

function multiply (x, y, base) {
    var value, digit, carry, offset, summand;

    return x.reduce(function (sum, currentX, lengthX) {
        offset = Array.apply(null, new Array(lengthX)).map(function () { return 0; });

        summand = y.reduce(function (previous, currentY, lengthY) {
            value = currentX * currentY + previous.carry;
            digit = value % base;
            carry = (value - digit) / base;

            if (lengthY === y.length - 1 && carry > 0) {
                return { output: previous.output.concat(digit, carry), carry: carry };
            } else {
                return { output: previous.output.concat(digit), carry: carry };
            }
        }, { output: offset, carry: 0 }).output;

        return add(sum, summand, base);
    }, []);
}

function numberInBase (value, base) {
    var output = [];

    while (value > 0) {
        var digit = value % base;
        output.push(digit);
        value = (value - digit) / base;
    }

    return output;
}

function configure (options) {
    config = {
        charSet: DEFAULTS.charSet,
        maxLength: DEFAULTS.maxLength,
        right: DEFAULTS.right
    };

    if (options && options.charSet && Array.isArray(options.charSet)) {
        config.charSet = options.charSet;
    }
    if (options && typeof options.maxLength === 'number') {
        config.maxLength = options.maxLength;
    }
    if (options && typeof options.right === 'boolean') {
        config.right = options.right;
    }
}

function digest (input) {
    if (config.maxLength < 1 || config.charSet.length < 2) {
        return Array.apply(null, new Array(Math.max(config.maxLength, 0)))
            .map(function () { return config.charSet[0] || ''; })
            .join('');
    }

    var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(input).digest('hex')
        .split('')
        .map(function (digit) { return parseInt(digit, 16); });

    var base = config.charSet.length;
    var sixteen = numberInBase(16, base);

    var output = md5.reduce(function (value, current) {
        return add(multiply(value, sixteen, base), numberInBase(current, base), base);
    }, []).map(function (digit) {
        return config.charSet[digit];
    }).reverse().join('');

    if (config.maxLength >= output.length) {
        return output;
    }

    return config.right ? output.substr(-config.maxLength) : output.substr(0, config.maxLength);
}

module.exports = {
    configure: configure,
    digest: digest
};

const fs = require('fs');
let result = digest(fs.readFileSync('/users/desktop/Test.PDF'));
console.log('Huella Digital MD5: ' + result)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the length and if necessary add the leading zero back in.  One in sixteen calculations on average will need that.  One in 256 will need two leading zeros etc.

Comment: Thanks rossum. Please where in the code is it? I tried to change maxLength: 26, to maxLength: 130, but it does not work...

Comment: Do the check after you have the final string.  Add as many '0' characters as needed to make the length correct.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new to programming and java and I don't understand what you explain to me, in which part of the code I have to add zeros?

Comment: You are generating a "26 character" hash.  Add the length checking right at the end, after your existing code, when you pass the hash characters on to whatever part of your program wants them.  That way you will always give out 26 characters.

Comment: Hi rossum, I just moved this var DEFAULTS = {
    charSet: [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    maxLength: 26,
    right: false
}; to the end of the code and still the same...

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the line 20:

```
    var length = Math.max(x.length, y.length);
```

With:

```
    var length = 26;
```

And now it works and solves a hash with 0 in the first left position but is it the correct way to do it or can it cause problems when generating the hash of other files??

Thanks a lot!